# How can I run RSpec tests on Gitlab CI using structure.sql for creating the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, rspec, gitlab-ci

I have a Rails project and I want to run the RSpec tests on every commit via Gitlab CI. Since the Docker container of Gitlab CI uses 'postgres' as host and not 'localhost' I configured this in database.yml. If I use the schema.rb everything works fine. It doesn't work anymore if I set 'config.active_record.schema_format = :sql' in application.rb since we use structure.sql for our project and not schema.rb.

The following error message appears:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test

Dropped database 'my_project_test'
Created database 'my_project_test'
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -q -X -f /builds/my_project/db/structure.sql my_project_test
Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `psql` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.
```

My database.yml looks like this:

```
default: &default
  username: admin
  password: 1234
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_project_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_project_test
  host: postgres
  port: 5432
```

And this is the .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
    - build
    - test

build-job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Hello"
test-job:
    stage: test
    image: ruby:2.6.3
    # Cache gems in between builds
    cache:
        key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
        paths:
            - vendor/ruby
    services:
        - postgres:15.1
    variables:
        POSTGRES_DB: my_project_test
        POSTGRES_USER: admin
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        RAILS_ENV: test
        BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
    before_script:
        # Bundler is not installed with the image
        - gem install bundler -v 1.17.2
        # Install dependencies into ./vendor/ruby
        - bundle install -j $(nproc) --path vendor
    script:
        - bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
        - bundle exec rspec
```

Comment: to restore the `structure.sql` file, rails needs a commando from the OS called `psql`; this command comes from the `postgresql-client`. So to solve this, you need to install on your process that package.